# the double parentheses beside subfigures

Tags: floats, subfloats

how can I omit the double parentheses beside subfigures, while i want to show label in text like this: 1.(a)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,aps,12pt]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{floatrow}   
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=top}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts} %for \mathfrak & \mathbb
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm,left=1.5cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\graphicspath{ {myfigures/} }
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[modulo]{lineno}
\modulolinenumbers[5]%prints every 5 lines
\renewcommand\linenumberfont{\normalfont\footnotesize\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{hyperref} %To hyperlink
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue,
filecolor=magenta,      
urlcolor=cyan,
citecolor=blue
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You provide only preamble to your document. Be so kind and add to it small (dummy) content which will show your problem?

Comment: The `caption` package is not (yet) compatible to the RevTeX document class, so I would suggest dropping it and loading `subfig` without `caption`: `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}`